# Will deleting a package in production delete the components in the package (fields, layouts, etc)?

Tags: metadata, package, unmanaged-package

We have about 10 custom packages in production.  As best as I can guess these were used to deploy fields etc to sandboxes c. 2008 and have not been used since.

[image: production packages]

I would like to remove them, as they occasionally cause rather annoying issues and are not being used for anything.  Currently I'm trying to uninstall a managed package we no longer need and I'm running into a dependency issue.

> This extension depends on the package you are trying to uninstall. Venture II

Once I go into the unmanaged package, I do see the delete button.  Before I press delete, I would like some guidance to be sure that deleting the package wont actually delete any fields or other metadata that are in the package.

[image: delete button]

I tried to test this in a sandbox, but I get the '[package was created in a production org so it cant be edited or deleted in a sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126211/cannot-delete-unmanaged-package-from-sandbox)' error.

And I know uninstalling a package will remove fields, etc.  I'm pretty sure this is a different scenario, but would hate to be wrong. Also if there are any considerations around the order in which I delete packages or anything else that could be helpful to know / learn / read, that would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that deleting packages will remove the components associated with it. [Here is](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_packages.htm&language=en_US&type=0) something you can read from Salesforce

> From the list of packages, you can:
>
> - Click New to create a new package, enter a package name and
>   description, and Click Save to store it in your list of packages.
> - Click Edit to update the package properties.
> - Click Del to delete the
>   package. **The components contained in your package are not deleted.**
> - Click the name of the package to view the details of the package.

Answer (score 1):

Packaging is a container for your components and you can delete them without any consequences and rest assured nothing will break .

Just be double sure to delete only those packages that you really want to get rid of them and do not accidentally delete a package which you need them else you will end up building again .(No loss except man hours )